# Stopping the indeterminate mode of of JProgressBar in SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, swingworker

I want to stop the indeterminate mode of the progress bar, once my `doInBackground` (method of SwingWorker) returns `null` (meaning when my task is done). Here is my code inside the button; when I run my code, I get an error. Here is the code:

```
private void StartButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         

final Main f22 = new Main();

initializer();

f22.getfile(FileName, 0);
f22.execute();

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        jProgressBar1.setIndeterminate(true);
        try {
            if (f22.doInBackground() == null) {
                jProgressBar1.setIndeterminate(false);                        
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6e1b0750, pid=4988, tid=5464
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b141
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (21.0-b11 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86              
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xa0750]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client  

  versions of Windows
#
```

Comment: See also [*Removing the indeterminate mode of JProgressBar*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656658/removing-the-indeterminate-mode-of-jprogressbar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be using your SwingWorker wrong. You should never call `doInBackground()` directly, and especially not right in the event dispatch thread -- this goes against the whole reason for using a SwingWorker -- but rather call execute on the SW. Add a PropertyChangeListener to the SwingWorker and change behavior based on that.

e.g.,

```
  final Main f22 = new Main();
  initializer();
  f22.getfile(FileName, 0);
  f22.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
        if (pcEvt.getNewValue().equals(SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE)) {
           // do your stuff here
        }
     }
  });
  f22.execute();
```